# How to display details in edit popup window with knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have a button on customer list form. On click of particular row edit button I want to show the details in the edit window.

How to pass the customer id to popup window?

```
<button data-bind="click: $root.edit"> Edit</button>
```

Comment: binding the selected item even in the popup might solve your problem. you can get selected item from list form and have a computed property, where the selected item will be saved in the computd property and use it to bind data in popup.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about the "show the details in the edit window" bit - that all depends what "edit window" means in the context of your code. Maybe you could create an "edit window" dialog for every Customer in the `observableArray` and toggle its visibility on click. [G_S's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29106616/how-to-display-details-in-edit-popup-window-with-knockout-js/29107270#comment46444195_29106616) to have some sort of "selectedCustomer" observable also sounds like a good idea.

As for passing the Customer ID around, I made a little [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2sooLot/6/) demonstrating how to do this.

**HTML:**

```
<h3>Click a row to obtain a customer's id:</h3>

<div data-bind="foreach: customers">
    <div data-bind="click: $root.selectCustomer" class="person">
        <div>Customer Name: <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </div>
        <div>Customer Age: <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
        </div>
        <div>Customer ID: <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var vm = function () {
    this.customers = ko.observableArray([{
        name: "Jim",
        age: "40",
        id: "1"
    }, {
        name: "Jack",
        age: "20",
        id: "2"
    }, {
        name: "Jill",
        age: "30",
        id: "3"
    }]);
    this.selectCustomer = function (customer) {
        alert(customer.id);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm);
```

In this code, the entire Customer object is passed to selectCustomer(), and all of the Customer's properties can be modified.

http://jsfiddle.net/r2sooLot/6/